# Why is Wine not installable on my system?

Tags: package-management, 12.10, wine

I upgraded on a fresh install to Ubuntu 12.10, and I've tried installing wine many times, but I always get this:

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. 
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine:
```

It won't let me install the dependencies either it says it needs another set of dependencies to install them. Using Asus KJ50 64bit OS, dual boot with Windows 7

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.15-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-droid
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did you remove wine before updating ?

Comment: can you copy the error and post it in your question ?

Answer (score 12):

I've been having the same issue, it turns out that with newer versions of apt and dpkg they support a feature called "Multi-arch". In simple terms, you can specify that apt pulls package info from repositories for architectures other than the native install, and install multiarch compatible packages from those repos.
For more detailed information, see:
http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Your issue specifically, is that the wine1.5-i386 is in the 32 bit wine repository, but not in the 64 bit repo, and your dpkg/apt are not configured to deal with this for some reason. To resolve:

Check your native architecture with:

```
sudo dpkg --print-architecture #in your case this should return 'amd64'
```

Other available architectures can be shown by:

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures #in your case this should not return anything
```

So you need to configure a new foreign architecture (quantal/12.10 or newer***):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Check your new arch is now available, update and install your package with apt:

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures #now this should return 'i386'
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install wine1.5 #and away you go!
```

=======

***Note that the Ubuntu dpkg in natty (1.16.0~ubuntu7 (reports 1.15.8.10)), oneiric and precise (1.16.1.2ubuntu7) uses a different syntax:*

```
echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is detailed, completed with comment on every step. It is clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow this procedure when installing wine :

open the terminal and type thes commands:
but first remove wine by the command : `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine
```

after adding the wine reprository which you already did. Using the software manager go to ‘edit’ and choose ‘software sources’. Select the ‘other software’ tab and click on ‘add’ at the bottom of the window. You now need to add the following line of code instead of the original Wine PPA link.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

You can now close the sources list and the software manager. Next to update your sources list open up the Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once your sources list has been updated you can install either the stable 1.4 Wine package or the 1.5 development package using the following commands:

Wine 1.4 (stable)

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

Wine 1.5 (development)

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

That’s all there is to it, you will now also continue to get the latest Wine releases and updates on your Linux, enjoy!

[source of the solution](http://www.ivegotavirus.com/how-to-fix-wine-in-linux-mint-13-maya/)

---

another solution: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: just did that it did not work, said it still doesnt have the dependencies?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*
i used this and it removed everything ive ever installed -_-

Comment: @RawX check the updated answer

Comment: As @RawX says, `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*` may remove more than you intend; `apt-get` doesn't use wildcards the same way as a shell. If your intention is just to remove all packages whose names *start* with `wine`, use a regular expression: `sudo apt-get purge ^wine` In general, for package removal commands that use wildcards or regular expressions, it's advisable to simulate it on some machine first, by replacing `sudo apt-get` with `apt-get -s`. This shows you what it will do without actually doing it. (Of course this doesn't always predict the results on another system.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an error when trying to install the i386 package on a 64 bit install.
try following this guide for your system!

http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit#head-77def7ca75193f24e358dba3dd6bcf674bd61b37

I know this because this is what I had originally done.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not installable, because it depends on i386 architecture which isn't there in your system.

To add it, try:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

update your apt repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install wine again:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Alternatively you can `--force-architecture` by using `dpkg`.

Answer (score -1):

First I recommanded to remove wine with configuration files

```
sudo apt-get  --purge wine*
```

Update system and upgrade packages, Fix dependency

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Remove Unnecessary packages if any

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now Install wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

Clen cache

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: What is the intention behind `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*`? This removes more than just packages whose names start with `wine`, so if that's all you want to remove, you should use `sudo apt-get purge ^wine` instead. (Use `apt-get -s` in place of `sudo apt-get` to see what any `apt-get` installation or removal command will do, without actually performing the actions.)