# Unmet dependencies error when installing wine

Tags: wine, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Wine not installable on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.16-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-droid
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I get this error when trying to install wine. Please help!

Comment: Please supply more information about your system. What version of Ubuntu? How were you trying to install wine, through the terminal or the package manager?

Comment: If you you are on 64bit OS Try to install ia32-libs

Comment: Im on Ubuntu 32 bit 12.10

Comment: Im on 12.10 and have tried trough the terminal.on 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Carter.

To fix this problem, I recommend installing Synaptic Package Manager. This is a tool that allows you to fix and diagnose problems with your packages graphically.

[image: Install via the software center] 
Download Synaptic

[How to use Synaptic Package Manager (Documentation)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)

From there, you are able to find broken packages. It should look something like this:

[image: Broken Packages]

[How to fix broken packages with Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How_to_fix_broken_packages)

Good luck.