# dependancy error wine 64

Tags: wine

Have followed instructions per Luis Alvarado Nov 16 '12 18.36 and get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.24-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/211530/unmet-dependencies-error-when-installing-wine?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system (last one is more important).