# Trying to install wine for play on linux

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

This is my first time using Ubuntu, I tried to get Play On Linux to run Microsoft Office, but it wanted Wine.

But when trying to install Wine with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download Wine (wine1.5-i386 Broken Package Error)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228630/how-to-download-wine-wine1-5-i386-broken-package-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Wine not installable on my system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system)

Answer (score 1):

**Adding the PPA Repository:**

Open the Software Sources menu by launching the **Ubuntu Software Center** and selecting **Edit->Software Sources**. Choose the **Other Software** tab and click **Add**.

[image]

Then, **copy and paste** the line below.

`ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

**Warning: Beta packages**

*The 1.7 packages here are beta packages. This means they will periodically suffer from regressions, and as a result an update may break functionality in Wine. If the stable 1.6 Wine version works for you, then you may not want to use these beta packages.*

**Installing Wine:**

Once you have added the repository, you are ready to install.

To get the most recent Wine 1.7 beta, paste `apt://wine1.7` in address bar.

To install the older, stable Wine 1.6 version, paste `apt://wine1.6` in address bar.

**Alternative Command Line Instructions for Installing Wine:**

*It is also possible to add the PPA and install via the terminal.*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Answer (score -1):

try

sudo apt-get -f install

or visit

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html