# Package dependency problems with wine

Tags: installation, 12.10, wine, dependencies

I am running Ubuntu and trying to install Wine. When I run `sudo apt-get install wine`, it gives the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried using the `-f` flag and this doesn't help. Ubuntu software centre returns a similar error.

Edit: Here is what is returned when trying to run `sudo apt-get install wine1.4`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.4 : Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-droid
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: not adding the -f flag, only with the -f flag, so `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: How will it know I am trying to install Wine if I just do `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: It knows about the problems you had before, so it will know that you tried to install wine but failed, now it will try to correct it. If all goes right this command will actually install wine.

Comment: All doesn't go right, the same error as before is returned.

Comment: This appears to be a bug:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/994309 please go to this link, make an account, and click the text which says '...does this bug affect you?' (near the top). For now can you try: `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, then `sudo apt-get update`, and finally `sudo apt-get install -f`. Sorry, for all the trouble Ubuntu is causing you ;)

Comment: @GerhadBurger ok, found the same info a few moments ago [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system). EDIT: Seems to work - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I flagged this question as duplicate of the question you mentioned to keep the site clean. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Try this file from WineHQ and run it as root or with the `sudo` command

1. Download the dependency build file from [here](http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-wine-deps.sh).
2. Copy and paste it into a gedit and save it with a `.sh` extension
3. Open terminal and run it as root i.e:

   ```
   sudo sh filename.sh
   ```