# can't update wine

Tags: wine, dependencies

I'm using wine 1.6.1 and want to upgrade to 1,7,13 but it always every time want update:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1~ubuntu13.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1~ubuntu13.10.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help me? I'm using ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the official wine repository

In terminal, run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

### To install Wine 1.7

**Warning : This is a beta version**

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

### To install Wine 1.6

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

### Alternatively,

To get the most recent Wine 1.7 beta, go to this url from your browser`apt://wine1.7`

To install the older, stable Wine 1.6 version, go to this url from your browser `apt://wine1.6`

See [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system) for more reference

Comment: You can find more info from [here](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the i386 dependency "wine1.7-i386" first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
```

And if that is successful, then install wine1.7:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Comment: If you cannot successfully install wine1.7-i386, add the i386 architecture with dpkg: `dpkg --add-architecture i386`