# Install Wine 1.7 on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wine

I can't install wine1.7 on ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
winetricks est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
winetricks passé en « installé manuellement ».
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine1.7 : Dépend: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.14-0ubuntu1) mais ne sera pas installé
           Dépend: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.14-0ubuntu1)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

And if i try to install the dependences :

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7-amd64
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine1.7-amd64 : Dépend: wine1.7:any (= 1:1.7.14-0ubuntu1)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».


$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Dépend: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628-2) mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Wine not installable on my system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You have dependency problems.
Fire up the terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.

Here are the commands you should use:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get -f install
```

then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

again:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you still have a problem please add a comment to this question or edit you answer.

Comment: How  did you get the buttons? I couldn't find that option.